# Super slow Excel, how can I increase the performance?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have an Excel file which is super slow, like copying a cell to another takes more than a minute which should be done in a second. When I try to copy 10 cells to another area, Excel stops responding. I had the same problem before and deleted old information on the file, previously cached data. It worked and solved my problem but right now funny I just cant find the same option. I would be glad if you can help me!I have Excel 2007.

File size with Excel 2003 : 1,9 MB (Works in compatibility mode, original file, I saved it as 2007 to find a solution)

File size with Excel 2007 : 96,4 KB

Excel is using normally 200-300 KB memory but when I want to make the copy operation I want it climbs up to 1.800 KB and later gives the error MS Office Excel encountered a problem and need to close, Debug, send error report etc.

There is no formula and external data, my computer is also new. I would like to find the option again to delete the old data or cache, cant remember exactly now but if I remembered I wouldn't ask the question.

The computer has no problem, everybody is having the same problem with this excel file, all other excel files are working fine and fast on my computer.This file is a list of products and every week it is updated/overwritten.The file is on my local computer.

OS: Win 7 64bit

Comment: There's nothing like "clear file cache" in Excel that I'm aware of.  Is it only this specific file, or are others operating the same way?  Does closing and reopening Excel help any?  Anyone else have this problem with that file? Is the Excel file local or on a remote server?  Since you say the computer is new, have you checked the disk drive(s) to confirm they are operating up-to-snuff and didn't come from the factory with a problem?  Have you checked over [Excel sheet becomes very slow](http://superuser.com/questions/626187/excel-sheet-becomes-very-slow?rq=1) yet?

Comment: @techie007 The computer has no problem, everybody is having the same problem with this excel file, all other excel files are working fine and fast on my computer.This file is a list of products and every week it is updated/overwritten.

Comment: _Is the Excel file local or on a remote server?_  Like, are all these users using the same copy of the file (say, via a share)?

Comment: @Anarkie - How much memory does the Excel process use when this file is used?

Comment: @techie007 The file is on my local computer

Comment: Make a new Excel file, copy your data over, and check if the new file is still slow.

Comment: @JanDoggen did not work... got the same error MS Office Excel encountered a problem and need to close, Debug, send error report etc.

Comment: Create a new Excel file and transfer the data over to it from the slow file. See if that helps to start off with

Comment: had this problem once, the culprit was a darn VB script. have you checked?

Comment: @LorenzoVonMatterhorn There is no VB Script

Comment: It could be due to a volatile cell with many dependents. Try running the profiler in the [FormulaDesk](http://www.formuladesk.com) add-in. Profile the volatile cells.

Comment: Have you tried to select all "CTL+A" then right click and copy , then right click paste special, paste values only. It sounds like there is some issues in the original sheet. Are there any macros in the background? Have you deleted all non relevant tabs ?

Comment: Make sure there are no formulas by going to "Find & Select" on the home tab then click "Formulas". Then check if there is any conditional formatting that is being applied to entire columns by going to "Conditional Formatting" on the home tab and clicking "Manage Rules". You mentioned this is a list of products that is updated/overwritten, is this a manual process or linked to another sheet/database?