# 2 Monitors 2 Excel Sheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel, multiple-monitors, microsoft-excel-2007

I have 2 Monitors and want to observe on one monitor 1st sheet and on the other monitor 2nd sheet but no matter how many excel files I open they are all on one monitor.

Can I split them to two screens?

I have Excel 2007 and working on 2003 file. Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: Update many years later... The View > New Window feature worked well for me: https://superuser.com/a/640247/74576

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The only way I have been able to accomplish this is to open a brand new instance of Excel (either from the start menu, task bar via right click in Win7/Vista, etc) and open the second file from that new Excel window.

If you continually use the same excel window to File -> Open new files, it will keep the documents all grouped into the same instance and move every file to the same monitor like you're experiencing.

Comment: Thanks this worked, would you have time for http://superuser.com/questions/643401/super-slow-excel-how-can-i-increase-the-performance as well?

Comment: I don't know of a fix for that other thing off the top of my head, but I'll research when I can.

Comment: Worked for me too. Upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

You can also spread the Main excel file across both screens and then use View > Arrange Windows > Tile Vertically.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Would you have time for this http://superuser.com/questions/643401/super-slow-excel-how-can-i-increase-the-performance ? please...

Answer (score 2):

You need to open 2 instances of Excel, move each one to a monitor and then open the files.

Comment: So essentially, exactly what @panhendel has said in his answer?

Comment: Exactly! @panhendel was faster than me. :)