# Excel Spreadsheets vs Dual Monitor

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am working with two separate spreadsheets and i have dual monitors. I'm using MS Office 2010.  How can I get one SS to open on the primary monitor and the second SS to display on the secondary monitor?  Thanks!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need two excel windows side by side, on different monitors, in the same instance](http://superuser.com/questions/273977/need-two-excel-windows-side-by-side-on-different-monitors-in-the-same-instance), [2 Monitors 2 Excel Sheets?](http://superuser.com/questions/676409/2-monitors-2-excel-sheets)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to have two instances of the excel application open, one for each monitor.

Otherwise, extend the application window across the monitors and manually adjust the workbooks to be one on each monitor. I advocate two instances of excel.

Answer (score 0):

you can open another instance of Excel, if it's Windows 7 you can Right click Excel in the taskbar, and click 'Microsoft Excel 2010' in the menu, to open another instance.

But note that Excel can be a bit tricky if you are opening more than one instance, mainly because of the personal.xlsb template